# When is the function $f(x) = |x|^m$ in $W^{1,p}(B)$, where $B$ is the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces

Let $B$ denotes the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For what value does the function

$$f(x) = |x|^m$$

belongs to $W^{1,p}(B)$.

My answer is $m>2-n$, but I am not sure if it is correct. The partial derivative is

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = m x_i |x|^{m-2}$$

using the fact that $|x|^{-k}$ is in $L^1_{loc}(B)$ if $k<n$. Thus if $m>2-n$, we have

$$ ||f||_{L^p} + ||\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}||_{L^p} < +
\infty$$

which is the definition of $W^{1,p}(B)$. Am I missing something?

Comment: You didn't account for $p$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Thanks for the comment. I don't follow it though. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Additionally to Umberto comment, you should replace $m-2$ by $m-1$ as $|x|^{m-2}\,x_i \leq |x|^{m-1}$.

Comment: @Morcus The result you state about $\vert x\vert^{-k}$ is for $L^1$, but you are asked when the function and its derivative are in $L^p$. So you need to know they are integrable after being raised to the power $p$. This will alter your answer.

Comment: @podiki Right! Thanks